# Why Firefox is default browser for webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We know that for firefox , driverserver.exe is not required while it is required for chrome or IE. Please help me to understand why Firefox is default Implementation of WebDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver :
Firefox Driver

Firefox driver is included in the selenium-server-stanalone.jar available in the downloads. The driver comes in the form of an xpi (firefox extension) which is added to the firefox profile when you start a new instance of FirefoxDriver.

Comment: selenium-server-stanalone.jar do not come into picture when we are using selenium webdriver, right?

Comment: selenium-server-stanalone.jar contains both Selenium RC and Webdriver.  
  
Again, for Firefox, the server side component is built as a firefox plugin, [ Firefox supports plugins and works with profiles. So WebDriver extracts the embedded webdriver xpi, creates an anonymous profile, adds this plugin to it and then spawns the browser]. That way all of your webdriver commands that you trigger via the client bindings can interact with the embedded server.
as described here http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=705

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is baked in the jar file. It comes as a xpi, which is the extension of firefox . As soon as you instantiate the *FrefoxDriver* it gets added. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver)